# Como pasar el resultado executeSql a una función en javascript

Tags: javascript

Hola estoy haciendo una consulta, a un tabla Web Sql y quiero que el resultado pasarlo a una función independiente les dejo el código (el valor que quiero pasar es el de la variable ***xa*** y el nombre de la función es ***get_textrandom***) cuando ejecuto el código me dice que la variable ***xa***  no esta definda.

```
    //Extraemos los datos de la tabla.
    sqlselect = "SELECT texto FROM textos  WHERE npregunta = '"+npreg+"'";
    tx.executeSql(sqlselect,[],function (tx, result){

            if (result.rows.length){
                for (var i = 0; i < result.rows.length; i++){
                     row = result.rows[i];
                     x += row.texto + ",";
                }
                //Quitmos la ultima coma
               var xa = "["+x.substring(0, x.length-1)+"]";
            }else{
                console.log("No items");
            }
        },error);       
});


function get_textrandom(xa){

    var i = Math.floor((Math.random() * 6) + 1);
    $("#text2").html(xa[i]);
}
```

Comment: revisa el resultado de ` var i = Math.floor((Math.random() * 6) + 1);`

Answer (score 0):

Prueba lo siguiente

```
  //Extraemos los datos de la tabla.
    sqlselect = "SELECT texto FROM textos  WHERE npregunta = '"+npreg+"'";
    tx.executeSql(sqlselect,[],function (tx, result){

            if (result.rows.length){
                for (var i = 0; i < result.rows.length; i++){
                     row = result.rows[i];
                     x += row.texto + ",";
                }
                //Quitmos la ultima coma
               var xa = "["+x.substring(0, x.length-1)+"]";
               get_textrandom(xa);
            }else{
                console.log("No items");
            }
        },error);       
});


function get_textrandom(xa){

    var i = Math.floor((Math.random() * 6) + 1);
    $("#text2").html(xa[i]);
}
```

Adicionalmente ten en cuenta que las consultas a web SQL son asincronas.